# How can I discard only the changes not in the staging area?

Tags: git

How can I discard only the changes not in the staging area?

Suppose:

```
$ cat file.txt
Hello
$ git add file.txt
# edit file.txt
$ cat file.txt
Hi
```

How do I get the contents of `file.txt` to what it was before the last edit and after the `git add` command without editing it back manually?

Real case scenario is I have these files which are programatically generated but must be committed to the repository (e.g., Django migrations). I want to regenerate the files, but only commit some of the changes made. So I use `git add -p` to select the changes I want, and then I want to discard the changes not selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To revert (to discard the modifications in) a specific file *x*:

```
git checkout x
```

To revert all the modified files after the last `git pull` command:

```
git checkout .
```

Otherwise, you can discard the unstaged changes:

```
git stash save --keep-index --include-untracked
git stash drop
```